# Unit test: Mock service class with constructor dependency injection

Tags: symfony, phpunit, typo3

Is it possible (and recommendable) to create mocks of service classes which load dependencies by constructor injection?

Class:

```
class SettingsService
{
  public function __construct(SiteFinder $siteFinder)
    {
      $this->siteFinder = $siteFinder;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
$mockService = $this->getMockBuilder(SettingsService::class)->getMock();
```

This leads to error: ***Too few arguments to function ... 0 passed***

Is there a way to make use of the autoloaders in phpunit? Or do I have to create single mocks of all injected classes and assign them to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Unit Tests, it's all: "You're on your own", however a good way is to use the prophecy framework to inject stubs into your class.

If you don't need the objects in your test, this is totally the way to go, if you depend on them, you'd rather want to use a Functional / Integration test, where you get the Dependency Injection by the framework shipped (but for the trade-off of speed), but depends on what you want to test / what's your scope is.

Comment: Hi Benni. Thanks for your response. So "functional" is the new "unit" :-)

Comment: Haha. Not really. If you have a lot of dependencies, you need a lot of mocking, so a functional is indeed better. But it also adds to writing code with the SOLID principle in mind, so Unit tests are easier to do. Rule of thumb: If you have to do a lot of mocking, then it's actually a Functional, not a unit test.